# Particle system converted to objects keeps multiplying when i try to join them using ctrl j

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, particles

i made a hair particle system and then made real instances of it. Then when i try to join them using ctrl j the whole thing changes and the same objects gets multiplied many times. pls help
I'm using blender 3.3

Answer (score 0):

All instances share the same mesh data after converting. When you perform the join operation this mesh data changes - it becomes consisting of all meshes you have joined. But as soon as all objects initially used in the particle system continue sharing the same mesh data - which now is the joined mesh - each of them starts to look like multiplied mesh.

To avoid it, before joining meshes, first go to the `Object Data Properties` tab (green triangle icon in the bottom right panel) and press a digit near the object data name. This digit determines how many objects in the project share the same mesh data-block. By pressing it you make a copy of the mesh data block of the active object and assign this newly created mesh to this object. This way the active object starts using its individual mesh data-block and you can join other meshes to it without affecting other objects which used the same mesh data-block.

You don't have to make individual data blocks for each object you are joining, only for the active one.